# Программа не находит установленный opencv в docker

Tags: linux, docker

Dockerfile

```
# start with ubuntu
        FROM ubuntu:16.04
        EXPOSE 8080
        ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
        RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

        # Update packages and install basics
        RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
            wget \
            unzip \
            git

        # Install dependencies
        RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libgtk2.0-dev cmake python-dev python-numpy libeigen3-dev yasm libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev default-jdk ant libvtk5-qt4-dev

        # Install pip
        RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
        RUN python get-pip.py && rm get-pip.py
        RUN pip install --upgrade pip

        # cd to /tmp and clone repos for OpenCV and extra modules
        WORKDIR /tmp
        RUN git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git -b 4.0.1
        RUN git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git -b 4.0.1

        # Create build folder
        WORKDIR /tmp/opencv
        RUN mkdir /tmp/opencv/build
        WORKDIR /tmp/opencv/build

        # Build OpenCV
        RUN cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/tmp/opencv_contrib/modules ..
        RUN make
        RUN make install
        RUN echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
        RUN ldconfig

        ENV PATH="/usr/local/lib:${PATH}"

        ADD /target/tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
        ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.core.Mat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# start with ubuntu
    FROM ubuntu:16.04
    EXPOSE 8080
    ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
    RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

    # Update packages and install basics
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        wget \
        unzip \
        git

    # Install dependencies
    RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libgtk2.0-dev cmake python-dev python-numpy libeigen3-dev yasm libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev default-jdk ant libvtk5-qt4-dev

    # Install pip
    RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    RUN python get-pip.py && rm get-pip.py
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip

    # cd to /tmp and clone repos for OpenCV and extra modules
    WORKDIR /tmp
    RUN git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git -b 4.0.1
    RUN git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git -b 4.0.1

    # Create build folder
    WORKDIR /tmp/opencv
    RUN mkdir /tmp/opencv/build
    WORKDIR /tmp/opencv/build

    # Build OpenCV
    RUN cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/tmp/opencv_contrib/modules ..
    RUN make
    RUN make install
    RUN echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
    RUN echo "/tmp/opencv/build/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
    RUN ldconfig

    ENV PATH="/usr/local/lib:/tmp/opencv/build/bin/:/tmp/opencv/:/tmp/opencv/build/:/tmp/opencv/build/lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:${PATH}"
    ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/tmp/opencv/build/lib"
    ADD /target/tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ENTRYPOINT java -cp /tmp/opencv/build/tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/local/lib/*:/tmp/opencv/build/bin/*:/tmp/opencv/build/lib/* -Djava.library.path=/tmp/opencv/build/lib/ -Dloader.main=ru.hh.tin.core.Application org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```